# Running this from command line in Java

Tags: java, classpath

I cannot run the following program from command line the usual way:

```
package animal_package;

public class my_animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello animal");
    }
}
```

E.g. from Command prompt: I go to `"D:\Java\src\animal_package"` where my java program is and compile it:

```
D:\Java\src\animal_package>javac my_animal.java  
D:\Java\src\animal_package>java my_animal  
Error: Could not find or load main class my_animal.java
```

I have looked on Google and came around class path problem but couldn't make any sense from it all.

Which command line would be correct in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd ..` then `java -cp . animal_package.my_animal`. The package is **part** of the *fully qualified class name*. Or,

```
java -cp .. animal_package.my_animal
```

Comment: @user963241 The **parent folder** of the *current folder*. Same as using `cd ..` (but without modifying the *current folder*).

Comment: Ah, the `src` folder right. So after setting it to that only then I can say "animal_package.my_animal" and it will get the right path, right?

Comment: @user963241 The package is part of the class name, the directory structure must match (i.e. `src` contains a folder `animal_package`, and that folder needs to have `my_animal.class` in it).

Answer (score 3):

To compile:

```
javac my_animal.java
```

To run (from src directory):

```
java animal_package.my_animal
```

Comment: It works from `src` but how can i make it work from directory where `.java` and `.class` was compiled to?

Comment: Only by removing the package declaration.

Comment: The package declaration from my source file?

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the class either from src directory using:
javac animal_package\my_animal.java
OR  from animal_package directory using: javac my_animal.java

To run the program from src directory use 
java animal_package.my_animal  OR  java -cp . animal_package.my_animal

Comment: the answer does not state clearly enough that the `java` executable mut be invoked from the folder `D:\Java\src` and not from the package folder. Please  consider [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41385887/edit)-ing that in.